# the best pattern to keep references to global collections in Backbone

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, backbone.js, marionette

I'm developing an application in Marionette, but the topic refers to raw Backbone as well.

In my app, I've got many collections. Among them, there are 3 important ones, that are used all over the application (e.g. user data, such as names, which is displayed in most of views). The main question is: what is the best way  (a good pattern to follow) to keep references to collections in Backbone/Marionette? I came up with few ideas below:

- should I attach them as attributes of the `Application` object? If so, I'd have to pass the reference to `Application` object to all views, then views to their subviews, subviews to subsubviews, etc. But this seems a lame and ugly design.
- instead, I could pass each collection separately, but this seems even worse solution, because I can't predict which (sub)view will ever need a collection. Keeping those nested references in order would be much more difficult than passing the `Application` object which I can pass once, always.
- the is also a possibility to import the `Application` as a singleton. I'm using requireJS, most of the modules return constructors now (constructors of views, models and collections). Now the app module returns Application constructor, but instead, it could return the Application object. Then if a view requires to display some data from the collections, it could just require the app module and that's all.
- finally, basing on the previous point, I thought I could create a plain map of collections and make it a singleton just as before. This is only to disable all views to have access to `Application` object, which still seems a bad pattern.

Please, suggest what you think is the best (commentson points above are welcome as well). I just need a good design pattern here. As far as I know, Marionette docs doesn't suggest anything here.

Answer (score 1):

I follow the suggestions made in David Sulc's book [Backbone.Marionette.js: A Gentle Introduction](https://leanpub.com/marionette-gentle-introduction). (also the next book on goes into how to then sturcutre the same project with require https://leanpub.com/structuring-backbone-with-requirejs-and-marionette)The code examples he uses are available on github so you could look at the final example which to get an idea of what he does if you didn;t want to buy the book but i really recommend it as it really helped me with how to structure my projects.

To start I have setup an Entities module. The structure of the files also follows this I have an Entities folder which has separate entities.

Each Entity file concerns all actions and stucture of that particular entity. I like this approach as I when i want to edit an entities strcuture or method of getting data from the server i only need to go to one place to make this change.

Interactions with entity are handled through marionettes req/res system. In this way you can expose a handler to the rest of your app but they don;t need to be concerned with how that req gets handled as long as it brings back the required response.

Here is an example of one of my entities to show what i mean - My app needs a collection called positions at various stages so this is something that is loaded early in the app then is available through-out it's life-cycle.

```
 //i am using require so i define my app to use
 define(["app", ], function(MyApp) {
     //All of this will be added to the Entities module so if i want direct access 
     //i can go Myapp.Entities.whateverEntityIhaveDeclared
     MyApp.module("Entities", function(Entities, MyApp, Backbone, Marionette, $, _) {

         //model (nothing new here)          
         Entities.Position = Backbone.Model.extend({
             urlRoot: "api/positions",

             defaults: {
                 name: "",
             }
         });
         //collection again nothing new here
         Entities.PositionCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
             url: "api/positions",
             model: Entities.Position,
             comparator: "name"
         });

         //an init function to attach a position collection onto Entities module so it can be available throughout my app
         var initializePositions = function() {
             if (Entities.positions === undefined) {
                 Entities.positions = new Entities.PositionCollection();
             }
         };

         //
         var API = {

             //returns a jquery deferred promise so that this request can easily be handled async
             loadPositionEntitiesRemote: function() {
                 //init positions make's sure i have the collectoin avaliable if it
                 //has not yet been defined
                 initializePositions();


                 //setup defer object
                 var defer = $.Deferred();
                 //I actually use a custom sever object here when dealing 
                 //with ajax requests
                 //but because my app always go through this API i can 
                 //easily swap out  how the collection is retrieved.
                 // Here is an example using backbones fetch
                 Entities.positions.fetch({
                     success: function() {
                         defer.resolve();
                     },
                     error: function(data) {
                         defer.reject(data);
                     }
                 });

                 //setup promise to return
                 var promise = defer.promise();
                 return promise;
             },


             //get the positions collection from here i could 
             //directly access the attributes or add to the collection
             refrencePositionEntities: function() {
                 initializePositions();

                 return Entities.positions;
             },

             //get a position from the collection based on id
             //
             getPositionEntity: function(positionId) {
                 initializePositions();

                 return Entities.positions.get(positionId);
             }
         };


         //setup handlers for the app to use
         MyApp.reqres.setHandler("position:entities:remote", function() {
             return API.loadPositionEntitiesRemote();
         });

         MyApp.reqres.setHandler("position:entities:refrence", function() {

             return API.refrencePositionEntities();
         });

         MyApp.reqres.setHandler("position:entity", function(id) {
             return API.getPositionEntity(id);
         });

         MyApp.reqres.setHandler("position:entity:new", function(position) {
             return new Entities.Position(position);
         });
     });

     return;
 });
```

now to use this in my app here is an example of how it can now be used

```
 someFunction: function(){


    //so early in the app i will get the positions
    var positionPromise = MyApp.request("position:entities:remote");
    $.when(positionPromise).done(function() {
                     //do what ever as data has been loaded
                 }).fail(function(data){
                  //something failed so handle here might through up an error page but up to you
                 }).always(function(){
                  //something to always do no matter if fail or sucess
                 });

 }

 anotherFunction: function(){


 //later in the app in another controller i might to get the collection
 // I could also get it through MyApp.Entities.positions but i rather use the
 // API set up so if i ever decided i want to add so checks or something in
 // when retrieving the collection its super easy

 var positionsCollection = MyApp.request("position:entities:refrence");



 }
```

Not sure if i've done a great job explaining this but if you are looking for a ideas on good design in marionette check out the book as it explains this a lot better than i have just done